# iproute2 table 0 is different from table local

Tags: linux, iproute

We all know that these commands generate the same output:

```bsh
ip route list
ip route list table 254
ip route list table main
```

And this command lists some special rules related to local and broadcast addresses as well:

```bsh
ip route list table local
```

However, replacing `local` with zero (as listed in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`) generates a lot of output:

```bsh
ip route list table 0
```

Why is the last command so different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *local* table is one of the default tables: 255, as can be seen in [upstream repository](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/tree/etc/iproute2/rt_tables?h=v5.4.0)'s `rt_tables`:

> ```
> #
> # reserved values
> #
> 255   local
> 254   main
> 253   default
> 0 unspec
> #
> # local
> #
> #1    inr.ruhep
> ```

The table 0, here written *unspec* is also known internally as *all* by *iproute2* tools. It's not really a table. It represents *all* tables and means to not specify one in particular. So when you type one of those:

```
ip route show table 0
ip route show table all
ip route show table unspec # only if present in /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

it will display *all* routing tables, including table 254 for the *main* table (which is the one used when not specifying the table), table 255 for the *local* routes and any other non-empty table you might have created. As there are different tables instead of only one, this command will also add in the output the extra parameter `table X` (except for table 254/*main*) for each displayed table X, so its output can be reused to add a table entry in the right place.

As the output will include the *local* and the *main* table, it will always have more lines than only one of of those tables: longer output.